# Collection view different cell height with multiple section

Tags: swift4

I need different cell height with multiple section in collection view. I am using this code but extra white space is there. I am attache a screen shot.[image]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {

```
        let width : CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width - (40 + 10))/2 //150
        var height: CGFloat = 207
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:

            height = 207
        case 1...2:

            height = 120
        case 4:

            height = 207
        default:
            break
        }
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }else {
        let width : CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width - (40 + 10))/2
        let height : CGFloat = 241
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of UICollectionViewLayout are you using? Which of the whitespaces do you want to get rid of?

Comment: Can you please check my image, which i have already attached.

Answer (score 0):

You need staggered collection view in order to achieve this, Find more details with an example [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)